# Close SMTPAppender's thread pool when Tomcat shuts down

Tags: java, multithreading, email, tomcat, logback

I'm using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)'s [SMTPAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) to send e-mails when certain logging events occur on my [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/).

The SMTPAppender can send e-mails asynchronously. Then however shutting down Tomcat fails because Tomcat can't close SMTPAppender's thread pool.

Is it somehow possible to close this thread pool when Tomcat is shutting down?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out: [Stopping logback-classic](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#stopContext)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Tomcat, it seems that configuring Logback's Tomcat valve should resolve this issue for you:

http://logback.qos.ch/access.html

Configuring the Valve will result in Tomcat automatically shutting down the associated `ExecutorService` upon shutdown.

Comment: I don't want to configure HTTP access logs which I don't need just to close the thread pool.

Comment: I didn't notice any requirement for setting up HTTP access logs. Regardless, if you're looking for a "clean" Logback way of shutting down Logback's threadpool, this is it.